# Fastest way to generate magic numbers

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, chess

I have some idea of how the magic bitboard works, really it just lessen the amount of bits on a certain occupied bitboard and to convert the already available to save occupied bitboard to a smaller value to increase its speed.

So I have this code which allows me to generate the rooks and bishops magic number, currently the generation time for rooks is about **5.9s** on A i5 10400F, while on the bishops takes about 0.05s.

I am trying to generate the magic numbers for both the rook and bishop multiple times, trying to get a smaller and smaller magic number, however since the generation for the occupancy for a certain index takes a while, its quite tiring waiting for the generation to complete.

**I think it has to do with poping the least significant bit:**

```js
//* bitboard class
PopLSB() {
    if (this._bitboard === 0n) return -1n

    const lsb = this._bitboard & -this._bitboard
    const lsb_index = this.GetLSBIndex(lsb)
    this.XOr(lsb)

    return lsb
}

GetLSBIndex(lsb) {
    return Math.log2(lsb ? lsb : Number(this._bitboard & -this._bitboard))
}
```

```js
function IndexToUBigInt64(index, bits, mask) {
    const bitboard_mask = new BitboardClass(mask)

    let result = 0n

    for (let i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
        const square = bitboard_mask.PopLSB()

        if (index & (1 << i)) result |= 1n << BigInt(square)
    }

    return result
}

function FindMagicNumber(square_index, bits, diagonal) {
    const occupancies = new Array(4096)
    const attacks = new Array(4096)
    const used_attacks = new Array(4096).fill(0n)

    const attack_mask = diagonal ? diagonal_masks[square_index] : level_masks[square_index]
    const target_squares = diagonal ? diagonal_squares[square_index] : level_squares[square_index]
    const occupancy_indicies = 1 << bits

    //* The slowest part of the generation
    for (let index = 0; index < occupancy_indicies; index++) {
        //* Responsible for the generation to take a while
        occupancies[index] = IndexToUBigInt64(index, occupancy_indicies, attack_mask)

        attacks[index] = MaskSlidingAttaks(occupancies[index], target_squares)
    }

    for (let _ = 0, fail = 0; _ < 100000000; _++) {
        const magic_number = GenerateMagicNumber()

        if (BigInt(new BitboardClass((attack_mask * magic_number) & 0xff00000000000000n).CountBits()) < 6) continue

        for (let index = 0, fail; !fail && index < occupancy_indicies; index++) {
            const magic_index = (occupancies[index] * magic_number) >> (64n - BigInt(bits))

            if (used_attacks[magic_index] === 0n) {
                used_attacks[magic_index] = attacks[index]
            } else if (used_attacks[magic_index] !== attacks[index]) {
                fail = 1
            }
        }

        if (!fail) return magic_number
    }

    console.log("***Magic number failed***")
    return 0n
}
```

I have tried using the `Math.clz32` but this just made the generation slower. there where also other ways that I have tried such as using a while loop, I also wanted to try the wasm i64 but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: `Math.Log2` is a slow operation.  It would be better for you to build a look-up table.  It would only be as big a the number of bits you have.

Comment: Look up the [De Bruijn](https://www.chessprogramming.org/BitScan#De_Bruijn_Multiplication) multiplication trick. I'm not sure how effective it will be in javascript but probably better than doing Math.log2.

Comment: I just did some benchmarking with arguments that are a power of 2 (as is the case here), and the difference between `Math.log2`, `Math.clz32` (which only returns the correct value for 32 bit numbers, so it is not good for this 64 bit case), and a lookup table (`Map`), and they are very close -- so close that sometimes one wins, then the other.

Comment: @trincot Map is probably quite slow i'd assume. With the De Bruijn multiplication lookup you can directly index into a const array.

Comment: @JaneDoe, that needs not only a lookup, but also some extra multiplication. In JavaScript that is not going to act nice. I benchmarked it, and it came out as the slowest solution by far.

Comment: I should add that on closer look, the lookup `Map` was always slower than `Math.Log2`. So far I can only confirm the choice that anata0 made as the best available (for that part).

Comment: Alright, then perhaps another way ... I see there is a `CountBits` member function for the `BitboardClass`. What is the implementation? If we have an efficient popcount function, then getting the LSB can be trivial. 

`GetLSBIndex(bitboard) { return CountBits((bitboard & -bitboard) - 1) }`

Comment: So far I have tried many of this [BitScan](https://www.chessprogramming.org/BitScan#De_Bruijn_Multiplication) methods, and still the `Math.log2` is still the fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of something different and came up with the idea of initializing the attacks and occupancies, when the Generation function is called. I figured that the generation is using the same attacks and occupancies over and over again. With that, I just need to save the attacks and occupancies on A object, then index the attacks and occupancies for the next generation to use it.

Now the amount of seconds from the rook is about 0.125s, as for the bishop about 0.008s. I am able to complete 100 generation in 13-14 seconds.

```js
function GenerateAttacksAndOccupancies(square_index, bits, diagonal) {
    const attack_mask = diagonal ? diagonal_masks[square_index] : level_masks[square_index]
    const target_squares = diagonal ? diagonal_squares[square_index] : level_squares[square_index]
    const number_of_bits = 1 << bits

    const attacks = new Array(number_of_bits)
    const occupancies = new Array(number_of_bits)

    for (let index = 0; index < number_of_bits; index++) {
        attacks[index] = MaskSlidingAttaks(occupancies[index], target_squares)
        occupancies[index] = IndexToUBigInt64(index, number_of_bits, attack_mask)
    }

    return { attacks, occupancies }
}

function InitSliderAttacksAndOccupancies() {
    for (let square_index = 0; square_index < 64; square_index++) {
        const _level = GenerateAttacksAndOccupancies(square_index, LEVEL_BITS[square_index], false)
        LEVEL_ATTACKS_AND_OCCUPANCIES.attacks[square_index] = _level.attacks
        LEVEL_ATTACKS_AND_OCCUPANCIES.occupancies[square_index] = _level.occupancies

        const _diagonal = GenerateAttacksAndOccupancies(square_index, DIAGONAL_BITS[square_index], true)
        DIAGONAL_ATTACKS_AND_OCCUPANCIES.attacks[square_index] = _diagonal.attacks
        DIAGONAL_ATTACKS_AND_OCCUPANCIES.occupancies[square_index] = _diagonal.occupancies
    }
}
```